# binary classification with labels of varying quality

Tags: classification, binary-data, labeling, sample-weighting

I have a binary classification problem, where half my development data is labeled by a reliable source, and the other half by a less reliable one. Note that each instance gets a label from only one of the sources, not both. What are some standard approaches to handling this type of situation?

One way I could think of is as follows: let's say we know for the unreliable source that
$\mathbb{P}(y_{\textrm{true}} = 0| y_{\textrm{source}} = 0 ) = q_0$ and $\mathbb{P}(y_{\textrm{true}} = 1| y_{\textrm{source}} = 1 ) = q_1$. Note that these probabilities are 1 for the reliable source. Then in model training and in evaluation, use instance weight=

- $q_0$ for unreliable label 0 instances,
- $q_1$ for unreliable label 1 instances,
- 1 for all reliable label instances

Is that a reasonable approach? Could this be extended to the case where every instance has a different $\mathbb{P}(y_{\textrm{true}} = y_{\textrm{source}} )$?
Any better approaches?

Comment: There isn't a single, standard way to handle problems with multiple annotators of varying quality, even though it's very commonly encountered in the real world. One approach is outlined in [Modeling Multiple Annotator Expertise in the Semi-Supervised Learning Scenario](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3529) by
Yan Yan, Romer Rosales, Glenn Fung, Jennifer Dy proposes one method based on latent variables, and also has a decent lit review (but is a bit dated -- from 2012).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. However, it's about multiple annotators for the same instance each of whole reliability is unknown. The situation I describe is annotators of known reliability for mutually exclusive and exhaustive subsets of the data.

Comment: The model they propose doesn't require annotations for overlapping portions of the data. "In the multi-labeler problem addressed in this paper, points may be labeled by zero, one, or more labelers." Knowing that your annotators have different reliabilities helps, but there's still value in quantifying that reliability and incorporating it in the model lets you be precise about the influence of each annotator on the model. In any event, as I said, this paper isn't the only example of multi-annotator models, so you can probably review the citing/cited papers and find one that suits your needs.